# Redirect to another view than the initialRoute on click on the notification - Flutter Local Notification

Tags: flutter, notifications, local

I developed a notification that is time-dependent (launch notification in `n` seconds). It works and it's fine.

But when I click on the notification it launches the main page while I want to launch another view of the app either through `Navigator.pushNamed` or call the stfl Widget...

I use Flutter Local Notification:

```
class NotificationService {
  static final NotificationService _notificationService =
      NotificationService._internal();

  factory NotificationService() {
    return _notificationService;
  }

  final FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin =
      FlutterLocalNotificationsPlugin();

  NotificationService._internal();

  Future<void> initNotification() async {
    // Android initialization
    final AndroidInitializationSettings initializationSettingsAndroid =
        AndroidInitializationSettings('@mipmap/ic_launcher');

    // ios initialization
    final IOSInitializationSettings initializationSettingsIOS =
        IOSInitializationSettings(
      requestAlertPermission: true,
      requestBadgePermission: true,
      requestSoundPermission: true,
    );

    final InitializationSettings initializationSettings =
        InitializationSettings(
            android: initializationSettingsAndroid,
            iOS: initializationSettingsIOS);
    // the initialization settings are initialized after they are setted
    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.initialize(
      initializationSettings,

    );
  }



  Future<void> showNotification(
      int id, String title, String body, int time) async {

    await flutterLocalNotificationsPlugin.zonedSchedule(
      id,
      title,
      body,

      tz.TZDateTime.now(tz.local).add(Duration(
          seconds: time)),
      //schedule the notification to show after n seconds.
      const NotificationDetails(
        // Android details
        android: AndroidNotificationDetails('main_channel', 'Main Channel',
            channelDescription: "ashwin",
            importance: Importance.max,
            priority: Priority.max),
        // iOS details
        iOS: IOSNotificationDetails(
          sound: 'default.wav',
          presentAlert: true,
          presentBadge: true,
          presentSound: true,
        ),

      ),

      // Type of time interpretation
      uiLocalNotificationDateInterpretation:
          UILocalNotificationDateInterpretation.absoluteTime,
      androidAllowWhileIdle:
          true, // To show notification even when the app is closed
    );
  }
}
```

And this is my trigger code:

```
class LocalNotification extends StatefulWidget {
  const LocalNotification({Key? key}) : super(key: key);

  @override
  State<LocalNotification> createState() => _LocalNotificationState();
}

class _LocalNotificationState extends State<LocalNotification> {
 

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    tz.initializeTimeZones();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return Scaffold(
      drawer: Menuimagine(),
      appBar: AppBar(
        automaticallyImplyLeading: false,
        title: Center(child: Text("Notification Locale")),
      ),
      body: SafeArea(
        child: ListView(
          children: <Widget>[
            
            TextButton(
              onPressed: () {
                NotificationService()
                    .showNotification(1, "7 secondes", "7 secondes", 7,);
              },
              child: Card(
                child: ListTile(
                  contentPadding: EdgeInsets.all(10),
                  title: Text("Schedule Notification"),
                ),
              ),
            )
          ],
        ),
      ),
      bottomNavigationBar: BottomBar(),
    );
  }
}
```

I don't know how to implement it, I looked at `onSelectNotification` but I can't do it.
Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

You can pass the route name as payload to the notification while creating it, and on the onClick listener for the notification, get the route name from the payload and navigate to it.